# Apply a parent style change to all checkboxes in group when a "check all" javascript function is run

Tags: javascript, jquery

We currently use a javascript function to change the color of a parent DIV element when a checkbox within that element is checked.  This works great and is handled via the following:

```
  $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked")){
        $(this).parent().addClass("redBackground"); 
    }else{
        $(this).parent().removeClass("redBackground");  
    }
  });
```

Recently, we added a separate javascript function that allows for all checkboxes in a specific group to be checked or unchecked via the checking or unchecking of a checkbox at the top of that group:

```
function toggleGROUPNAME(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('GROUPNAME');
  for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  }
}
```

However, despite trying everything that we can think of, we can't figure out how to get the second function--the function that handles the checking or unchecking of all of the checkboxes in the group--to also change the parent DIV's background color on that event.  Any help, suggestions, or examples would really be appreciated.

Thanks so much.

Richard

Comment: IMO `this.checked` is a cleaner approach than `$(this).is(":checked")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could trigger the change event explicitly:

```
$(checkboxes).change();
```

If the checkboxes of one group will always have the same parent, then it is sufficient to trigger the event for only one checkbox:

```
$(checkboxes[0]).change();
```

This would go after your loop:

```
function toggleGROUPNAME(source) {
  // don't forget var!!
  var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('GROUPNAME');
  for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  }
  $(checkboxes).change();
}
```

Comment: Wow.  Amazingly fast and spot on.  The checkboxes have different parents, so $(checkboxes[i]).change() is what I needed.  Again, thank you... I'll mark this as best when I'm allowed to do so in seven more minutes!

Comment: In that case just use `$(checkboxes).change();` after the loop, as I have shown You don't have to trigger the event for ever element individually. Let jQuery handle this.

Answer (score 0):

```
    function toggleGROUPNAME(source) {
      checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('GROUPNAME');
$("input[type='checkbox']").removeClass("redBackground");
      for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
        checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;

    $(checkboxes[i]).parent().addClass("redBackground"); 
      }
    }
```

Comment: That would always add the class, even if `source.checked` is `false`.

Comment: Still the same issue. Besides, I don't think the OP wants code duplication.